# How to prohibit change checkbox(checked/unchecked) by doubleclicking on row?

Tags: .net, windows, forms, winforms, devexpress

[image]

Hello there, I have one problem. I want to be able to: 
    1) When I click one time, I change checkbox status. I want to leave that opportunity. 
    2) If I double click, I want to be able to open another form. But when I double click on the row with checkbox I open another form and change checkbox status. So, how to fix it?

I have already made that when I do 2), I back previous checkbox status and take the form, but it's not good. Maybe you can offer smth...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a timer to distinguish between a single and double clicks. Please refer to the example in the [How to: Distinguish Between Clicks and Double-Clicks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-distinguish-between-clicks-and-double-clicks) article to learn more about this approach. If this does not help, please share more details about your current implementation.